# IntelliJ has stopped printing stack traces when my app fails

Tags: intellij-idea

I have frequently been seeing this error in IntelliJ (Ultimate 2020.2.3):

```
Cause: cannot assign instance of java.util.Collections$EmptyList to field java.lang.StackTraceElement.moduleVersion of type java.lang.String in instance of java.lang.StackTraceElement
```

It doesn't seem to be able to show me any stack traces from my app.  This behavior started with an upgrade some weeks back.

I tried running with `--stacktrace` but it made no difference.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this error? Could you please provide a code sample to reproduce a problem?

Comment: @Stevey Have you found any solution to this issue? I'm experiencing a similar problem (latest intellij 2021.1,  gradle 7.0) every time the application produces warning or an error during compilation.

Comment: @MartinBG No, no solution.  I honestly don't remember anymore where I was seeing stack traces -- it was either the debug window or the console window.  But it's been so long since I've seen a stack trace, through multiple upgrades including 2021, that I don't know what this functionality used to do. E.g. was it compile or runtime? Don't remember. I use a shell when I need to see a stack trace now.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem after I updated my IntelliJ to the latest (2021.2 Ultimate). I managed to fix the issue by changing the Gradle JVM from the Project SDK to the one from Gradle directory (AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.9 in my case).

Comment: Thanks, I was also using AdaptJDK and having the same issue, switched back to Jetbrain's open JDK and the error is gone.